# $.each for value json, how is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can done `$.each` for following json code as this(for name):

**1:** 11 11
**2:** 666666666 99999 777777 1221
**3:** 55555 00000000 222222222 333333333

```
{
    "reunits": [
        {
            "reun": [
                {
                    "name": "11",
                    "price": "77192276",
                    "extra": "11",
                    "hotel_id": "77192276"
                },
                {
                    "name": "11",
                    "price": "77192276",
                    "extra": "11",
                    "hotel_id": "77192276"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "reun": [
                {
                    "name": "666666666",
                    "price": "15190364",
                    "extra": "11",
                    "hotel_id": "15190364"
                },
                {
                    "name": "99999",
                    "price": "15190364",
                    "extra": "11",
                    "hotel_id": "15190364"
                },
                {
                    "name": "777777",
                    "price": "15190364",
                    "extra": "11",
                    "hotel_id": "15190364"
                },
                {
                    "name": "1221",
                    "price": "15190364",
                    "extra": "11",
                    "hotel_id": "15190364"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "reun": [
                {
                    "name": "55555",
                    "price": "11",
                    "extra": "33",
                    "hotel_id": "15183965"
                },
                {
                    "name": "00000000",
                    "price": "11",
                    "extra": "33",
                    "hotel_id": "15183965"
                },
                {
                    "name": "222222222",
                    "price": "11",
                    "extra": "33",
                    "hotel_id": "15183965"
                },
                {
                    "name": "333333333",
                    "price": "11",
                    "extra": "33",
                    "hotel_id": "15183965"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My try is this(not work):

```
$.ajax({
...
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.reunits['reun'], function (index, value) {
                    $('.li_show').append('<li>'+value.name+'</li>');
                });
            }
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(data.reunits).each(function(i,j){
$.each(j,function(x,y){
$.each(y,function(f,g){
console.log(g.name);
 $('.li_show').append('<li>'+g.name+'</li>');

  });
 });
});
```

**edit**

```
$(data.reunits).each(function(i,j){
$.each(j,function(x,y){
$var=" ";
$.each(y,function(f,g){
$var+=" "+g.name;
//console.log(g.name);
  });
   $('.li_show').append('<li>'+$var+'</li>');
 });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4WQs/2/)

Comment: No, I want done each three times in tag li because there are three reunits.reun, as this: <li>11 11</li><li>666666666 99999 777777 1221</li><li>55555 00000000 222222222 333333333</li>

Comment: thanks for jsfiddle. please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4WQs/3/ my full json and what that i want. how is for this json code put each reunits.reun in tooltip each name_re?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {
    var parts = [];
    $.each(value.reun, function(k,v){
        parts.push(v.name);
    });              
    $('.li_show').append('<li><b>' + (index + 1) + ':</b> ' +parts.join(" ")+'</li>');   
});
```

Comment: This new code put all names in three `<li></li>`, i want put in three li as example in first post(1 2 3).

Comment: @JimBo: You didn't really specify how you wanted it printed.

Comment: @Rocket - i want it as this in three times loop:1= 11 11
  2= 666666666 99999 777777 1221
  3= 55555 00000000 222222222 333333333.

Comment: try now plz. sorry, I'm kinda sleepy:)

Comment: No, i want done each three times in tag li because there are three `reunits.reun`, as this: `<li>11 11</li><li>666666666 99999 777777 1221</li><li>55555 00000000 222222222 333333333</li>` ok?

Comment: It's what the latest code outputs except for the <b> tag. If you remove the <b> tag, it's gonna be right as you've just wrote.
 $('.li_show').append('<li>' + parts.join(" ") + '</li>');

Comment: Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4WQs/3/ my full json and what that i want. how is for this json code put each reunits.reun in tooltip each name_re?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$.ajax({
...
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {
       for(key in value){
          $.each(value[key], function(i, v){
             $('.li_show').append('<li>'+v.name+'</li>');
          });
       }             
    });
)}
```

You can iterate inner objects inside your array item by using `for` statement

Comment: @Paul: I think you meant `for`, not `foreach`.

Comment: It's better to do `value.reun` instead of `value[key]`.  There may be other keys that don't have `name` properties on their values.

Comment: @Rocket thanks for fixing my typo, yes I meant for, but not foreach. Not sure about value.reun as its not clear whether we need to process only this property or others as well.

Answer (score 0):

`reunits` in an array containing objects that have a `reun` property which is array of objects.  You first need to loop through the `reunits` array, and then loop through each `reun` array.

```
$.each(data.reunits, function(){
  var str = '';
  $.each(this.reun, function(){
    str += this.name+' ';
  });
  $('.li_show').append($.trim(str));
});
```

Comment: @JimBo: I know, but it should show you how to get each name.  I'll leave it up to you to output it somewhere, as you never specified how you wanted it output.

Comment: I want done each three times in tag li because there are three `reunits.reun`, as this: <li>11 11</li><li>666666666 99999 777777 1221</li><li>55555 00000000 222222222 333333333</li>

Comment: @JimBo: You need to specify that in the question, how are we supposed to know that's what you want.

Comment: Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4WQs/3/ my full json and what that i want. how is for this json code put each reunits.reun in tooltip each name_re?

Comment: @JimBo: I'm kinda busy, I'll look at later maybe.  As for your parse error, you need a `';` at the end of your JSON (before `data=$.parseJSON(data);`).